# Scala state, function purity and separation of responsibility

Tags: scala, state, scala-cats, cats-effect

I can't cope with how state should be implemented in Scala app.
Assume I want to have a number generator but generated numbers are not totally random. They depend on the previous generated number. So let's have initial 33 and in each next call I want to increase 33 by number from 0 to 10 e.g. 33, 35, 41, 42, 49... I tried this way:

```
class Generator {
  private val state: IO[LastValue] = IO.pure(33).flatMap(i => lastValue(i))

  trait LastValue {
    def change(delta: Int): IO[Unit]
    def get: IO[Int]
  }
  private def lastValue(initial: Int): IO[LastValue] = IO.delay {
    var lastValue = initial
    new LastValue {
      override def change(newVal: Int): IO[Unit] = IO.delay { lastValue = newVal }
      override def get: IO[Int] = IO.delay { lastValue }
    }
  }

  def generate: IO[Int] =
    for {
      delta <- IO.delay { scala.util.Random.nextInt(10) }
      lastVal <- state.flatMap(_.get)
      newVal = lastVal + delta
      _ <- state.flatMap(state => state.change(newVal))
    } yield newVal
}
```

but of course `_ <- state.flatMap(state => state.change(newVal))` does not modify my `val state`. Is any way to do it right that?

I guess this design may not fulfill the function purity principle. And I agree but on the other hand, is this right to force user of the `Generator` (let's call this class `User`) to care about the Generator's state? I mean to modify it into `def generate(prevGenerator: Generator): IO[(Generator, Int)]` and `generator` can be stored in `User` to pass is in the next call.
But it pollutes `User` class. Forces to know and remember about things which should be transparent, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the built-in `Ref` which is designed to manage concurrent mutable state in a RT way.
You also should prefer the built-in `Random`.

```scala
trait Generator {
  def next: IO[Int]
}
object Generator {
  def apply(init: Int, step: Int, seed: Int): IO[Generator] =
    (
      IO.ref(init),
      Random.scalaUtilRandomSeedInt[IO](seed)
    ).mapN {
      case (ref, rnd) =>
        new Generator {
          override final val next: IO[Int] =
            rnd.nextIntBounded(step + 1).flatMap { inc =>
              ref.updateAndGet(i => i + inc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Note how we hide both implementation details from the user.

Which then can be used like this:

```scala
object Main extends IOApp.Simple {
  override final val run: IO[Unit] =
    Generator(init = 33, step = 10, seed = 135).flatMap { gen =>
      gen.next.flatMap(IO.println).replicateA_(10)      
    }
}
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ugeoX38wQk6f6fEEdZ0rgQ/3)*.

Comment: I believe this is a great solution but in this case I would like to keep my form so no apply, mapN but class and the "look" of `generate` method. I simplified the example because in the real case, much more happens. I wonder if it is possible to change state of `LastValue`, from the method `generate`.

Comment: @LancerX Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with _"no `apply`, `mapN`"_, also _WDYM with _"the look of `generate` method"_? - You can just rename `next` from my example to `generate` and you can just use a class instead of an anonymous instance as I did. -The main point is that you manage state using `Ref` and that creating shared state has to return an `IO`.

Comment: This is the only way how I understand using `Ref` in my example
https://pastebin.com/5Tv8a6rc
But it changes nothing so I do it wrong

Comment: @LancerX yes, because you need to move the creation of the shared state _(i.e. the `Ref`)_ outside `Generator`. In other words, creating a `Generator` must return an `IO[Generator]` instead of a plain `Generator` because it contains state. - Thus, what you can do is `class Generator(state: Ref[IO, Int])`, and usually we hide that by making the constructor private and having a factory in the companion object, so that we ensure the `Ref` is not shared _(which is not wrong per se, but usually not what you want)_, but you just leave it like this and let the caller to pass the `Ref`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try defeat the beast :)

Comment: @LancerX btw, a final _"option"_ if you can't have the construction of `Generator` to return an `IO`, is to `unsafeRunSync` the creation of the `Ref` in the body of the class, that way you would get the mutable state out of `IO` and you then can use it as you tried. Note, however, that this is technically _"wrong"_.